# Why is it called a ring, a field?

Tags: measure-theory

In measure theory, there are set classes, rings, fields, etc. Does it have something to do with that of abstract algebra?

Comment: See [Why are rings called rings?](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/61497/242)

Comment: See [terminology about ring/algebra in abstract algebra and measure theory](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/22676/terminology-about-ring-algebra-in-abstract-algebra-and-measure-theory)

Comment: It appears to me that the question asked here is not the same as that linked above. Namely, the asker is interested in how the terminology in measure theory arose and if there is a connection to abstract algebra. My link is closer, but still not spot on.

Comment: @rghthndsd Right, my comment was not meant to imply that it was a duplicate of that thread.