# Can we imagine Rings practically?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, geometry, ring-theory

I start learning algebra Groups, Rings and fields and when I wondering about these words practically meaning these words has no relationship with the mathematical definition of these, and the second thing is practically somewhere a found example of Group like asymmetric group(Diheadrl group is practically seen in lifelike Mercedes-Benz has D3 symmetric) or in the understanding of some chemical compound.

But similarly, I know there are some great use/applications of this structure but I wanted to explore these Geometrically and I don't found some practical or Geometrically applications of Rings and Field?
Thank you in advanced

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/61497/why-are-rings-called-rings

Comment: I wouldn't spend time on trying to find deeper meaning behind those names. I'm sure there was some motivation behind them but it was so long time ago, likely to be long forgotten. Now it is simply an accepted convention.